# Count how many unique eulerian path are in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I know how to check if graph have an eulerian path. But, I wonder, is there any general solution to count, how many unique eulerian path exists in a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a case of directed graph there is a polynomial algorithm, bases on [BEST theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem) about relation between the number of Eulerian circuits and the number of spanning arborescenes, that can be computed as cofactor of Laplacian matrix of graph.

Undirected case is [intractable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Counting_Eulerian_circuits) unless $P \ne \#P$.